# What's the difference about database file locking between Oracle and H2?

Tags: java, oracle, h2, file-locking

If we want an data file able to visit by more than one H2 server, we may have to add `FILE_LOCK=NO` to the jdbc url. But H2 documentation [Database File Locking](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_file_locking) mentioned that **this is unsafe as another process is able to open the same database, possibly leading to data corruption**. What's the potential risk here if we use h2 in java application? Does oracle has the same risk if we don't apply file_lock to oracle?

Comment: The file lock in H2 does just that, prevents multiple processes from accessing the data store simultaneously.  The potential risks include dirty writes (where what has being written by one process is overridden by a second), corrupted writes (where a portion of a record is updated incorrectly) to inconsistency in the result sets for example. Generally speaking, you should only ever allow a single process access to the data store. Hence the reason why you have database servers that control the access to the underlying store. I would suspect that each DBS handles this differently